# Composite indices and range queries

Tags: database, indexing, multi-index

I have a medium size table, 50M records or so, capturing all property sales in a geographic region.  The initial thinking was to have a composite (multi?) index on the heavily queried fields, date (day precision), latitude  (high precision), longitude (high precision) and price.  Typical queries provide range values for all of these columns.  I am really struggling to logically understand how range queries work on multiple columns of type numeric (lat/long in this case).  Our data has a lot of unique values for lat & long and in my mind there would be huge fanout in the index.  [This image displays the fanout, just imagine thousands of unique values for both latitude and longitude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMl2A.png)

My question is, have DB indices come a long way and can handle this much better than my logical understanding of the problem?  If not, I would think the index could be much more performant if I introduced coarse values for date (eg month), lat & long (maybe use their integer value) to minimize the fanout.  the query would have a much more verbose where clause (eg month >= A and month < B and date >= C and date < D).  The index would filter on month, and the db would further filter on date (unindexed).  Again, just wondering if there is merit in this approach, or if the latest indices handle this by default.

We did try the index on the fine level values as mentioned in the description, hoping to realize better performance than what we are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I created a few test indices to try and produce different scenarios, it looks like, at least anecdotally, that for the queries I'm trying to execute, the db selects the fine grained indices.  I was thinking / hoping that by making the keys more coarse grained the range scan can be optimized across the first few keys, but it looks like that doesn't happen.  From my test data, if the first key can filter most of the data, it can further filter records as it traverses the index on the first key.  No real benefit in trying to optimize this further, at least I couldn't get the better performing index.